# Spring Beans survive application restart?

Tags: java, spring, swing

I have a very very strange problem here. I have a desktop application written with `Spring 3.0.5-Release` and `Java 6.0`. I'm also using Swing for the UI.

On startup, the application reads an `application-context.xml` file and instantiates a configuration bean from there, like this:

```
<bean id="config" class="my.blabla.Configuration">
    <property name="port" value="5555"></property>
    <property name="user" value="myUser"></property>
</bean>
```

In my application I'm using the properties from this Configuration bean.

Problem is now the following:

I package the application into a jar-file and deploy it on a machine. 
I follow the following steps:

1. In the `application-context.xml` I change the property **user** to **userA**.
2. Now I run the application. Everything runs fine. In the log-file property user shows **userA**.
3. **I close the application**.
4. In the `application-context.xml` I change the property **user** to **userB**.
5. I run the application. BUT In the log-file property **user** shows **userA**.

A few more infos. This does NOT happen when I debug the application. It only appears when the application is packaged and executed from command line.
I close my application via the default close button and have set this:

```
 setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Any idea, what is happening here? Is there a chance that spring beans somehow survive an application restart? Is there a chance that the java process is not shutdown?

I'm getting crazy. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Just a wild guess - Is the old app context getting cached anywhere ? Check the app context inside the packaged file - maybe it'll help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running from the JAR file?  Is the application context XML in that JAR file?  Did you re-create the JAR after you change the bean from `userA` to `userB`?  That would explain the mysterious behavior.

Spring beans don't survive a restart, any more than any in-memory value does.  Your expectations don't match reality.

Comment: Yes, I run from jar-file. The application-context is outside of the jar-file. If I recreate the jar-file after changing the bean, everything works just fine. If I don't recreate I get the described behaviour.

Comment: You have to re-create the JAR.  You should not have the app context outside the JAR.

Comment: What is the reason for the need of recreation? Why can't I have the application-context outside of the jar? Are there any issues I don't know?

Comment: I'm guessing that your app isn't doing what you think it's doing.  I can't tell unless I see your code.  How do you access the app context?  Loading from the CLASSPATH?  How do you tell the app where the app context is?

Comment: Thanks for your help, you pointed me in the right direction and I could figure it out. Seems like my 'find the application-context' algorithm failed if the jar resides in a folder with white spaces...

Comment: I'm glad to be some help.  Good luck.